# Two-compartment model for depot intramuscular injections

Tags: pharmacokinetics

I am trying to learn pharmacokinetics.

Let us consider an intramuscular [depot injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depot_injection) of $5 \,\pu{mg}$ ($5\cdot10^9 \,\pu{pg}$) of a drug, whose half-time is 4 days. Let us say that the initial plasma concentration is $C(0) = 50 \,\pu{pg/ml}$. After 3 days a blood test was taken and showed the plasma concentration $C(3) = 170 \,\pu{pg/ml}$.

We consider a two-compartment model in which:

- first-order absorption to the central compartment with rate $k_a$
- first-order distribution from the central compartment to the peripheral compartment with rate $k_d$
- first-order elimination from the central compartment with rate $k_e$

We plot the amount in the serum, by solving the system of differential equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} = - k_a x_1 \\ 
\frac{dx_2}{dt} = k_a x_1 - k_d x_2 - k_e x_2 \\
\frac{dx_3}{dt} = k_e x_2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Where $x_1$ is the amount in the depot, $x_2$ is the amount in the central compartment, and $x_3$ is the amount in the peripheral compartment.

We find that the amount of the drug in serum reaches, say $0.15 \,\pu{mg}$ ($1.5\cdot10^8 \,\pu{pg}$) on day 3. If we divide that by the amount of serum (e.g. $2.8 \,\pu{l} = 2800 \, \pu{ml}$), we obtain $$C(3) = \frac{1.5\cdot10^8 \,\pu{pg}}{2800 \, \pu{ml}} = 53571 \,\pu{pg/ml}$$ However the real concentration is just $170 \,\pu{pg/ml}$. Where does this all drug amount go? Why is there such a large mismatch?

I feel that I am missing something very basic.

---

**Note:** [Here](https://onlinehelp.certara.com/phoenix/8.3/topics/pkmodelcalc.htm#XREF_87164_Model_11) is an example of a two-compartment model.

Comment: You said you fit the model, right? What are you fitting it to? Can you plot x1, x2, x3 as a function of time?

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, I fit the model using the method of residuals. Since I cannot measure x1 and x3 directly, I used x2 only based on my measurements (blood tests). The curve does fit relatively well. It's just the number on a different scale. This is where I have this problem.

Comment: Well, you have all the numbers you need to calculate x1 and x3. Can you plot them all (the predictions, that is)?

Comment: I suspect there's either a problem with units, or something weird is happening with your model because you don't have enough information to distinguish between kd and ke.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, I can plot them. They fit the curve fairly well. Most importantly, the model gives x1 + x2 + x3 = 5mg for t = 0 ... +Infinity. It is possible to distinguish kd and ke due to phasing. I.e. distribution completes before elimination and it's easy to estimate elimination. With absorption faster than distribution and elimination, the model (and reality) gives a hump (peak) after 1-2 days. Like I said, it fits well. Just the scale is very different, which is the question here.

Comment: @Julia, it is difficult to comment the outcomes without your data and fitting protocol. I suggest you add data together with fits to the question.

Comment: Can you add the plot to your question? It makes absolutely no sense that you say it both fits well and that the concentration on day 3 is different from what you measure. And, based on the differential equations you posted, there is absolutely no separability of those parameters if you only have x2 measurements, so either you're using different differential equations or making other assumptions not mentioned in this post.

Comment: @Domen Here's the fitting protocol. https://www.pharmacy180.com/article/two-compartment-open-model--extravascular-administration---first-order-absorption-2527/ I need to figure out how to add an image here.

Comment: @Julia, no need for images, post your _data_, for example upload it to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @BryanKrause I'd love to have these experimental data (x1 and x3) and I agree, it makes perfect sense to have them to accurately validate the model, but really, there is no way to accurately measure the amount of a drug in a depot or tissues. If you saw any studies on how to that on a human body, please let me know.

Comment: @Domen What specifically are you looking for? 1) The experimental measurements of x2 2) ka, kd, ke 3) calculated curves for x1, x2, x3? I just want to make sure I do the right thing.

Comment: I know, I'm not suggesting you collect those data from x1 and x3, just pointing out that the model you present has no way to distinguish them. Kd + Ke is constrained, but not Kd and Ke separately. But yes, those three things: data, fitted K values, and plotted curves will help us figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: I think I found my problems. The experimental data I have are starting at the point in time when drug distribution is supposed to be complete (i.e. the beginning of the steady state). That is, at that time all the drug amount is supposed to be distributed to tissues (peripheral compartment). This is the 1st problem. The second problem is using the amounts in the system of equations, not the concentrations. The system of equations should use concentrations.